# Why does printing this object variable in the console return "undefined" after the value?

Tags: javascript

**jsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/d4rhf23x/

**Issue**: Everything is working as expected in terms of my scroll handlers, but if I do a manual of the object variable in question like so: `console.log(site.globalVars.scrollY);`, it *does* return the correct value, but then it also returns an `undefined` immediately afterwards.

**Script:**

```
<script>

    var site = {

        globalVars: {
            didScroll: false,
            scrollY: 0,
        },

        globalFuncs: {

            ifUserScrollsDoActions: function(){
                if ( site.globalVars.didScroll ) {
                    site.globalVars.didScroll = false;
                    site.globalVars.scrollY = window.scrollY;
                    console.log(site.globalVars.scrollY);
                }
            },

        },

        topMenuElements: {
            mobileMenuLink: document.getElementById('mobile-menu-link'),
        },

    };


    window.onscroll = function () {  
        site.globalVars.didScroll = true;
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        site.globalFuncs.ifUserScrollsDoActions();
    }, 250);


</script>
```

Comment: That's what a function returns by default, and `console.log()` is a function, and it returns `undefined` when you use it directly in the console.

Comment: Your fiddle link is to an empty fiddle.

Comment: If you're actually typing in the console, you might as well just type `site.globalVars.scrollY` instead of `console.log(site.globalVars.scrollY)`.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `console.log` as a function it logs the parameters to the console.

When you call `console.log` as a function from the console, it treats it like any other function in the console, and logs the `return` value.

`console.log` returns `undefined`.